# How to work with PDF in the backend of a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, pdf, backend

I have this college work to do and the task is to create an app in Flutter that will fetch data from this website:

https://www4.trf5.jus.br/diarioeletinternet/paginas/consultas/consultaDiario.faces
(Not all data, just the data with this filtering {Orgão = Seção Judiciária do Sergipe; Edição = Administrativa; Ano = from 2020 to 2023)

The frontend is almost done. Here is the Figma prototype of the app:

https://www.figma.com/file/ptRv10llFteb53yMhkTRo5/App-de-Consulta-Di%C3%A1rio-Eletr%C3%B4nico?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=G7949zSzsx6knXjl-1

The app needs to allow the user to download a PDF or filter by a name or process code.
(Let me know if you have any doubts about the app functionality)

So, the problem is that this website doesn't have an API and the data is in PDF format.
My initial idea is to download all the PDFs (from 2020 to 2023) using Python with playwright. But I don't know how to store this in a database and return to users because sometimes the app will not return all the text in the PDF, only a little part.

Im using Firebase for backend.

Any ideas bout how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use file_picker package and then look at this code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

Future<void> uploadPdf() async {
  final File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.custom,                         
 allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);
  final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final Reference ref = storage.ref().child('pdfs/${file.name}');
  final UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);
  final TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() =>     null);
  final String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final DatabaseReference databaseReference =     database.ref().child('pdfs/${file.name}');
  databaseReference.setValue(url);
}
```

Comment: A starting in Flutter/Dart. Can u explain this code pls?